# How mipmaps affect static batching on 2D sprites

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, sprite, mipmaps, texture-atlas

I am optimizing my 2D mobile game. There are many sprites with *POT size* all over the game and I have filled their `Packing Tag` to enable batching and also checked their `Generate Mip Maps` checkbox. All these sprites have *uniform scales* in the game and most of them are (1,1,1).

**What I intend to do is to minimize the number of Batches in the game.**

**What I want to figure out is how mipmaps affect the number of batches in a 2D game?**

### This is what I have tried:

I copied two sprites several times with different but uniform scales and reported the number of batches.

The circle has POT size and mipmap enabled; The square is not, it's just a sprite; Both have the same packing tag, so they reside in different atlases.

Also checking or unchecking `Static` for these game objects does not change anything.

[image: aenter image description here]
3 batches when two different sprites are drawn

[image]
7 batches when two different sprites are drawn but in a little bit different positions

[image]
1 batch when only one mipmap sprite is drawn

[image]
1 batch when only one non-mipmap sprite is drawn. the positions of the game objects are the same as 1st test case **where there were 7 batches**.

Comment: Have you tried frame debugger? `Window -> Frame Debugger`. It will walk you through all `drawcalls` so that you can see how a frame gets rendered.

Comment: thanks i'll try that